# Spark streaming job fails after getting stopped by Driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which reads in data from Kafka and does some operations on it. I am running the job over a yarn cluster, Spark 1.4.1, which has two nodes with 16 GB RAM each and 16 cores each.

I have these conf passed to the spark-submit job :

> --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3 --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 3

The job returns this error and finishes after running for a short while :

```
INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11,
(reason: Max number of executor failures reached)

.....

ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0:
Stopped by driver
```

**Updated :**

These logs were found too :

```
INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 3 containers from YARN, launching executors on 3 of them.....

INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver terminated or disconnected! Shutting down.

....

INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 2 containers from YARN, launching executors on 2 of them.

INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Starting Executor Container.....

INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint: Driver terminated or disconnected! Shutting down...

INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_e10_1453801197604_0104_01_000006 (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)

INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_e10_1453801197604_0104_01_000006. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e10_1453801197604_0104_01_000006
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

What might be the reasons for this? Appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: You probably have some other errors/infos before this that sound like __killing executor__, __lost executor__ . Can you look in the log for this and post those eror messages?

Comment: @RaduIonescu I have added some logs which looked speculative to me. Could you have a look. Thanks.

Comment: To me it seems you either call `sparkContext.stop()` or you are using too much memory in the driver (e.g. calling `collect()` on the whole _RDD_s). You could try running it requiring explicitly more resources or with a small dataset to confirm this.

Comment: I tried both. Even with a small dataset, it's happening

Comment: Are you using YARN log aggregation? Set yarn.log-aggregation-enable to true.

Comment: @JustinPeel Yes, it's set to true.

Comment: Can you add more logs, worker logs, both stdout and stderr?

Comment: This looks like a memory issue to me. Can you have a look in the container log for one of the failing containers. Search for "killing container" or "running beyond physical memory". Also, you may want to try increasing `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` - this has solved most of my memory issues when running on YARN.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Nope, there is nothing that says killing or running beyond memory. All I can see is a lot of "Container marked as failed.. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch ..."

Comment: How should I increase the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` ? I just tried increasing it to 1024 (before it was 348), but still the exception comes.

Answer (score 3):

can you please show your scala/java code that is reading from kafka? I suspect you probably not creating your SparkConf correctly.

Try something like

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ApplicationName");
```

also try running application in yarn-client mode and share the output.

Comment: `val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AppName")` this is how I create my spark conf in my scala code. I am running in a standalone cluster now, as this error was giving me too much headaches. So can't try in yarn-client mode

Comment: just to drill down your issue, you can run spark-shell in yarn-client mode.

Comment: run spark shell like
spark-shell --master yarn-client

Perform sample operations and see
val textFile = sc.textFile("file on hdfs")
textFile.count()

Answer (score -3):

I got the same issue. and I have found 1 solution to fix the issue by removing `sparkContext.stop()` at the end of `main` function, leave the `stop` action for GC.

Spark team has resolved the issue in Spark core, however, the fix has just been master branch so far. We need to wait until the fix has been updated into the new release.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12009

Comment: I am not calling sparkContext.stop() in my code btw.